# Under what situation an object should not be Clonable?

Tags: java, cloneable

The basic collection interfaces (List, Map, Set) do not extend `Cloneable` interface. This is done in order NOT to enforce Cloneability for concrete implementations.

All of the collection classes do implement `Cloneable` interface so they all are inherently Cloneable. Also `Cloneable` is a marker interface meaning it signals the compiler/JVM to do some additional work *behind the curtain*, so as make that object Cloneable.

Now my question is : What the situations where in you DO NOT want your object to be Cloneable?

Comment: The List, Map, Set extend Collection don'T they? So they implement clonable anyway

Comment: Nevermind, just checked the Collection-Framework - it does not implement Cloneable

Comment: I don't think a marker interface is a signal to do anything magical behind the scenes. It simply means that `instanceof Cloneable` will return `true`. (This is not to say that there isn't magic going on in calls to `clone()`; just a comment about the term "marker interface".)

Comment: I don't think a marker interface is a signal to do anything magical behind the scenes. It simply means that `instanceof Cloneable` will return `true`. (This is not to say that there isn't magic going on in calls to `clone()`; just a comment about the term "marker interface".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Singleton is a good case.  Another is anything where you have a reference to something on the system that you should only have ONE reference to.  For example, a Stream.  Having multiple objects point to the same input (or output) stream could cause all kinds of problems.

If you want to use `clone()`, consider creating a *copy constructor* instead.

Answer (score 2):

If your class holds a huge chunk of data then you may not want it to be cloned to stop keeping multiple copy of a big chunk of data.

Comment: I might need this in case I want to keep class holding huge chunk of data immutable and use its copy/clone whenever needed elsewhere. Just like strings.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to implement the Singleton pattern, you probably wouldn't want the resulting Singleton to be cloneable.

Comment: Whats the harm if my singleton is cloneable ?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't want to have cloneable threads :X
Neither cloneable resource classes or session beans